# Perl: hash does not allow alphanumeric keys in this special case

Tags: perl, hash, quoting

I find a strange behaviour by creating a hash:

```
perl -e "%x = (1 => 10, p2 => 20); while ( ($k,$v) = each %x ) { print \"key $k value $v\n\";}"
```

gives the following output:

```
key p2 value 20
key 1 value 10
```

But if I change the key p2 to 1p2 I get an error:

```
perl -e "%x = (1 => 10, 1p2 => 20); while ( ($k,$v) = each %x ) { print \"key $k value $v\n\";}"
```

The output is:

```
syntax error at -e line 1, near "1p2"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Why does it give an error?

(Win10, Strawberry Perl v5.30.0)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To quote from [`perlop`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.32.0/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) (Emphasis added):

> The "=>" operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string **if it begins with a letter or underscore** and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores.  This includes operands that might otherwise be interpreted as operators, constants, single number v-strings or function calls.  If in doubt about this behavior, the left operand can be quoted explicitly.

Since `1p2` begins with a digit, that special behavior of `=>` doesn't apply. You have to quote it like a normal string to prevent the parse error.

Answer (score 2):

You should do

```
perl -e '%x = ("1" => 10, "1p2" => 20); while ( ($k,$v) = each %x ) { print "key $k value $v\n";}'
```

Quote the keys of the hash

Comment: I edited the answer. This works for me. single quote the entire perl script and double quote the keys of the hash. Moreover the print at the end should be double quoted too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I used Windows. On windows you have to enclose with double quote. Yes, I know that using quotes it works but I'm wonder why this does not works without quoting.